# Oldest Native American written literature?

Tags: history-of-literature

What's the oldest written publication that was written in a Native American language?

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by "book"? Native American literature [was originally](https://www.encyclopedia.com/arts/culture-magazines/native-american-literature) largely an oral tradition, and even their first written literature might not have been what you'd call a "book". Secondly, what do you mean by a language "created by" a Native American? I assume you're not looking for books in [constructed languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) - do you mean a native American language? From my brief research, it seems much of their early written literature was in English.

Comment: I suspect this will be one of the lost Mayan codexes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_codices

Comment: Sorry,I meant any written publication in a invented written alphabet.

Comment: What do you mean by "invented written alphabet"? Aren't all written alphabets invented — Is there such a thing as an uninvented written alphabet? Or do you mean a written alphabet invented specifically for that Native American language, which may restrict the language to Cherokee or Cree.

Comment: Invented specifically for a Native American language.

Comment: I've made a hefty edit to your question, clearing up a number of misconceptions (you don't seem to be asking about constructed languages - *are* there even any languages that were *invented* by Native Americans? - and you said you're asking for any written publication, not necessarily what we'd call a "book"), and given it an upvote as it's now a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Four codices**

According to Britannica four codices exist.

[Native American Literatures, Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/Native-American-literature/Written-literatures)

> Four codices are known to exist: the Dresden Codex, the Paris Codex, the Madrid Codex, and the Grolier Codex.

**Dated to between the classic and conquest period**

The codices are dated to between the classic and conquest period.

[Paris Codex, Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Paris-Codex)

> The set of year-bearers appearing in the codex offers a clue to the date of its production, placing it midway between the Classic and Conquest periods of Mayan history.

**Classic period**

Just to give us an idea of when this period is, the classic period ends around the 10th century.

[Written literatures, Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/Native-American-literature/Written-literatures)

> Maya hieroglyphs on stone and wood are confined largely to the Classic Period (300–900 CE),

**Conquest period**

The conquest period dates to the 16th century.

[Paris Codex, Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Paris-Codex)

> Paris Codex, Latin Codex Peresianus, one of the very few texts of the pre-Conquest Maya known to have survived the book burnings by the Spanish clergy during the 16th century

**Madrid codex 1400ad**

For a more precise estimate we can look at the Madrid codex which is estimated to have been written around 1400ad.

[Madrid Codex, Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Madrid-Codex)

> The Madrid Codex is believed to be a product of the late Mayan period (c. 1400 CE) and is possibly a post-Classic copy of Classic Mayan scholarship.

**Oldest Native American written literature?**

It appears to be either the Paris Codex written sometime between the 10th Century and 16th century, or the Madrid Codex, written approximately 1400ad, and thought to be a copy of earlier works